# parsing the uri key from json file is failing

Tags: json, python-3.x

Hi everyone I am trying to parse the `uri` key from a json file - it is properly loading the JSON file, but when I try to parse `uri` its failing with:

```
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper


with open(RROOT) as data_file:
    data = json.loads(data_file)
    for key, value in data.items():
        if key["uri"] in data:
            print(value)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you

Comment: change json.loads to json.load. json.loads takes a json string, json.load takes a file object. Both return a json object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, use json.load(takes file object) instead of json.loads(takes json string).

Secondly, key["uri"] will error out. If you're trying to just get the value for the key "uri" then do:

```
with open(RROOT) as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
    for value in data['uri']:
        print(value)
```

Comment: This got me closer. Thanks!